# C# How to correctly embed System.Data.SQLite libraries

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I have a C# project which uses System.Data.SQLite (.NET 3.5 version) libraries. Target platform is x86, target framework is 4.5.2.

Here's what I've done:

1. Added System.Data.SQLite to project's dependecies
2. Put System.Data.SQLite and SQLite.Interop.dll into project's root folder

The program runs perfectly on my PC (Windows Server 2008 R2) and my laptop (Windows 10). It also works on another PC (Windows 10).

However, when deployed to customer PC (Windows 7), I get DllNotFoundException on System.Data.SQLite. The PC has .NET Framework 4.5 installed. I tried both x64 and x86 System.Data.SQLite versions, but I still get exception.

If I remove System.Data.SQLite dependency and code, which uses this library, the program runs just fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

make sure that when you are deploying your app the DLL System.Data.SQLite  is included. 
In the picture you can see a demo with System.data, you should do the same with your DLL file, after build make sure that the DLL is in the source folder, and then your program should run.
and make sure that it support your current .NET version